# Linux console script to get file size and modified date based on prefix?

Tags: linux, shell, console

i need to write a consol script that recieves two parametrs - a location and a string prefix, and outputs the modified time and size of every file in the location that starts with the given prefix.

for example

```
myscript.sh /localdisk st
```

will out put something like

```
start.txt 11111 Dec 2 14:41
stop.jar 1432 Dec 1 11:21
stud.gz 1122 Nov 2 10:12
```

any ideas?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

something like this:

```
find $1/$2* -printf "%f %s %TY-%Tm-%Td %TH:%TM\n"
```